# How Can I send local video stream to server?

Tags: java, android, webrtc, webrtc-android, aiortc

> I am able to createOffer in local and send sdp to server.Also, got server answer and got sdp.
>
> Now, How Can I send my local video stream to server? I don't want server video.

```
private void startStreamingVideo() {
    //creating local mediastream
    MediaStream mediaStream = factory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS");
    mediaStream.addTrack(localAudioTrack);
    mediaStream.addTrack(localVideoTrack);
    localPeerConnection.addStream(mediaStream);

    MediaConstraints sdpMediaConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
    sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "false"));
    sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "false"));

    localPeerConnection.createOffer(new SimpleSdpObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateSuccess: ");
            localPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
            //remotePeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);

            callApiOffer(new Example(sessionDescription.description,sessionDescription.type.name().toLowerCase()));
        }
    }, sdpMediaConstraints);
}



private void callApiOffer(Example example){
        Utils.getInstance().getRetrofitInstance1().postRequest(example).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseExample>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseExample> call, Response<ResponseExample> response) {
                ResponseExample body = response.body();
                if (body != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, body.getType());
                    Log.e(TAG, body.getSdp());
                    // Here, I got server sdp and type="answer"
                    SessionDescription sessionDescription = new SessionDescription(Type.ANSWER, body.getSdp());
                    localPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
                    //doAnswer();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseExample> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

> Backend server is in Python aiortc
>
> I am getting "onIceConnectionChange: FAILED" 
>   Need I add to -> addIceCandidate ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to add peerconnection observer and in onIceCandidate method to send icecandidate. On receiving side you can add icecandidate.